# "What are the best language-learning resource collections for background X and interest Y?"

Tags: discussion

There was one time years back when I was looking for a computer, which I intended to use to run Linux and build software, and I posted a question saying to a hardware company's list saying "I think I need as much memory as I can get, skimp on the CPU, blah blah blah. If I'm wrong, I'd love to find out now instead of after I've committed money." There was a bit of radio silence, and the most response I got was along the lines of "I'm delighted that you've thought through what you want to use a computer for and what kind of computer you should be getting. Usually people have some rather vague idea that they want a computer, but haven't thought any of that too."

[Resources for learning Russian](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/833/resources-for-learning-russian) is not only one resource out there; it is exclusive enough that visitors are explicitly told that others playing in the same space will be marked as duplicate.

However, I believe I have a specific question, like I did with the computer question: "I want to speak spoken Russian. I am a philologist, I have read at length in the usual Western suspects other than German, and I read Russian reasonably and know how to improve my reading vocabulary. In Russian, I have besides print and web resources, access to an email list where the tone is probably as much conversational as one finds in written characters, and at my initiative I have probably access to as much spoken Russian as I want. I want to further develop an ear for spoken Russian, and speak aloud in a way that is intelligible to native Russian speakers."

This question seems slightly ill-fitted if it is attached to comments and answers on [Resources for learning Russian](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/833/resources-for-learning-russian) ; after reading it through, it seems heavy in text resources, probably including most of the best and most significant writing in Russian history. There are several online courses mentioned, but it is not clear to me which of them have which focuses and strengths, and whether the endgame is being able to hold a live spoken conversation, or read e.g. a Dostoevsky novel without a dictionary. I do not recall any resources being explicitly marked as intended to either develop spoken proficiency, or go from read-only proficiency to reading + spoken and possibly writing.

If russian.SE sticks with one master community wiki for language learning resources, could it be annotated according to the proficiency built? In some cases this is effectively done by stating that they offer classic texts, but I find nothing saying e.g. "Picks up where DuoLingo leaves off in spoken Russian proficiency."

Thanks,